# node.js get data from redis cluster, with ioredis, zrange method not returns correct number of data

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I use this: `redisClient.zrange(key, 1, 1)` and try to get all data by that key, but sometimes some data from list is missing, but when i check in redis data is there, also by c# client everything is ok.
Any ideas?

Comment: What's your data structure? You are using command for sorted set, while your problem description said that you want to get data from list?

Comment: yes data is sorted set, data structure is: key:  `[{ value:"SomeValue", score: 636142302000000000}, { value:"SomeValue1", score: 636142302000000002}, ]` like this. scores are c# date ticks, values some strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `zrange` command, the index is zero-based. `0` is the index for the first element, and `-1` is the index for the last element.

To get all data for the given key:

```
zrange key 0 -1
```